# Integral Involving Hermite Polynomial and rational function

Tags: definite-integrals, hermite-polynomials

We want to prove the formula

$$\frac{\int_{-\infty }^{\infty
   } \frac{e^{-x^2}
   H_n(x){}^2}{1+x^2} \,
   dx}{2^n n!}=\int_{-\infty
   }^{\infty }
   \frac{\left(\frac{1-x^2}{1+
   x^2}\right)^n
   e^{-x^2}}{1+x^2} \, dx$$
where $H_n(x)$ is the Hermite polynomial. The usual procedure of invoking the identity
$$\frac{\exp \left(\frac{2 x^2
   t}{1+t}\right)}{\sqrt{1-t^2
   }}=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }
   \frac{t^n H_n(x){}^2}{2^n
   n!}$$
Leads to the relation
$$\frac{\int_{-\infty }^{\infty
   } \frac{e^{-x^2} \exp
   \left(\frac{2 t
   x^2}{1+t}\right)}{1+x^2} \,
   dx}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}=\sum
   _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{t^n
   \int_{-\infty }^{\infty }
   \frac{e^{-x^2}
   H_n(x){}^2}{1+x^2} \,
   dx}{2^n n!}$$
It is not clear how to match powers of $t$ on both sides and obtain the desired formula.

Comment: Notably, Mathematica seems to conclude that these integrals (which I'll call $I_n$) can be written as $I_n=(-1)^{n}(A_n \sqrt{\pi}-B_n e \operatorname{erfc}(1))$ with rational coefficients $A_n,B_n$ where $\operatorname{erfc}$ is the complementary error function.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Upon invoking your summation identity, your new integrand contains the exponential factor $$\exp(-x^2)\exp\left(\frac{2tx^2}{1+t}\right)=\exp\left(-\frac{1-t}{1+t} x^2\right).$$

The coefficient $\dfrac{1-t}{1+t}$ may be eliminated by a judicious substitution. It remains to organize the new integrand so as to permit expanding in powers of $t$, and this is straightforward.

Comment: Got it, thank you. After making the substitution y=sqrt[(1-t)/(1+t)] x we obtain the term 1/(1-z) with z=t (1-y^2)/(1+y^2)

Comment: Right. And that's easy to expand in powers of $t$, yielding the desired result.